# Python compiled with --enable-optimizations is apparently slower

Tags: python, optimization, installation, compilation

I actually managed to make **Python slower with this flag enabled**. How is this possible? Has anything changed as of 2020?

I ran this snippet 3 times, both before and after. See results below.

```
import numpy as np
%%timeit
    ...: n = 0
    ...: while n < 100:
    ...:     a =  np.random.rand(1000,1000)
    ...:     b =  np.random.rand(1000,1000)
    ...:     c = np.multiply(a, b)
    ...:     n += 1
```

Without optimizations enabled (before enabling):

```
2.98 s ± 158 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

3.02 s ± 89.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

2.94 s ± 70.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

With optimizations enabled (after enabling; this should be faster, not slower..):

```
10.7 s ± 954 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

11.1 s ± 1.9 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

10.9 s ± 1.08 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```